# Difference between Checkout.Session and PaymentIntent in STRIPE?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, backend, payment

I am new to coding so bear my stupid questions.
I am working on STRIPE and using NODE JS.
Stripe docs are difficult to understand, can anyone help me explaining the difference between Checkout.session.create and PaymentIntent.

Thanks.

Comment: [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) is a fully hosted payment page. [Payment Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents) are an API that you'd use as a part of a custom Stripe integration.

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to the Stripe documentation at [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart)

You create `Session` for fully hosted (pre-built) payment page.

You create `PaymentIntent` when you need to integrate your custom payment flow.

Comment: When my payment is completed I get 3 events on my webhook, `payment_intent.succeeded`, `checkout.session.completed` and `charge.succeeded` which event should I consider as success and mark the order as **paid** in my application?

Comment: That's exactly the question I have ... a Checkout returns customer details like name and email, which is nice to have, Stripe's advice is to use payment_intent.succeeded, but a Balance transactions contains Stripe processing fees, which is a must have in my use case ...